# {"error_description": "Access token has insufficient scope: basic, names, email", "error": "insufficient_scope"}

Tags: 23andme-api

I have set permission for Email in Authorisation request.

https://api.23andme.com/authorize/?redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/receive_code/&response_type=code&client_id=""&scope=email rs123&select_profile=true

Using this url I have authorise the application. After this it redirecting me to redirect_uri and showing the code in request.
Here localhost url showing Internal 505 error.

Using this code I have post the request to get token> Below is the response.

{

```
"access_token": "28515f8734566dc0377ee0496e7b2d7d",

"token_type": "bearer",

"expires_in": 86400,

"refresh_token": "77cbfa595ee11b8a8e9d03acb09ad9f2",

"scope": "email rs123"
```

}

Now I am trying to request>curl "https://api.23andme.com/3/account/" -H "Authorization: Bearer 28515f8734566dc0377ee0496e7b2d7d"

Response error is instead of this If I am trying the same with demo_oauth_token its giving the response with details.

{"error_description": "Access token has insufficient scope: basic, names, email", "error": "insufficient_scope"}

Answer (score 1):

You need to send encoded url.For example your request url should look like:

```
https://api.23andme.com/authorize/?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/receive_code/&response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=email%20rs123&select_profile=true
```